# Simplest form of jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to send the simplest form of jQuery AJAX request to the server every 60 seconds to keep the user status as ACTIVE while the page is still open.

There is no need to get any response back from the server:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $(document).load('path/to/keep-user-active.php');
}, 60000);
```

Then the PHP script will do the necessary.

Comment: Change to `$.get("path")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest jQuery way is by using [$.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). If you don't need the response, just add the url without any callbacks.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('path/to/keep-user-active.php');
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Are you sure that cache won't be a problem in here?

Comment: @krzysiek.drozdz That will depend on if there is a cache. If there is, most likely the $.post will suit better

Comment: Or you could force some changing param or set cache to false, I guess...

Answer (score 1):

Simple AJAX w/ JQuery. Note you don't have to do anything with the result but whatever you do want to do with it, put code where #div1 is.

```
setInterval(function() 
{
       $.ajax({url: "path/to/keep-user-active.php", success: function(result){
       $("#div1").html(result);
       }});
}, 60000);
```

Comment: Well, OP clearly stated that he want to ignore the response, so I don't think it's the easiest form...

Comment: Right, he could then remove the response if he wants or do nothing with it. Sometimes it's good to know that you php script executed without error.

Answer (score 1):

Well... If you want to ignore the result and just use it as heartbeat, then this will be the easiest form, I guess:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get( 'path/to/keep-user-active.php' );
}, 60000);
```

But... If it is used for checking if user is online, then cache may be a problem... So this may work a little bit better:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/keep-user-active.php',
        cache: false
    });
}, 60000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This example calls `path/to/keep-user-active.php`, and sends the response through the [`success()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function. Replace `#ajax-result` with the div where you want your output to appear.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/keep-user-active.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#ajax-result").html(data);
        }
    });
}, 60000);
```